# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Glyphicons Changing the entire font family

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a un-ordered list. And I've added icons using the Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Using `Carme` Font from the [Google Fonts](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carme). For the normal text `Carme` font works very well.

But in the unordered list which i created, when I add a icon to it using the BS3, I'm getting icon and the `font-family` for that particular list is getting changed.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3H2c/1/) for a better understanding.

Notice the font-family both the list items with and without glyphicons.

I don't know whether the problem is..

Any suggestions will be helpful for me to overcome it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Icon tag needs to go outside `<a>` tag

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> One 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">One 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```